# Writing HTML in Single Page Application

Tags: single-page-application

Im trying to figure out what is the right approach of writing HTML (view) in a SPA.
let's say i have the shell (index.html) and i have a navigation bar at the top, and a container for setting up the view 
something like this:

```
<html>
   <body>
     <nav>
       <ul>
         <li>Home</li>
         <li>Signup</li>
     </nav>
     <div id=page-content> </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Do i generate the HTML on the client side for the signup page and for home page ?
or do i create containers on the page and fill them up?
How many code should go into my index.html is it suppose to stay empty as it is in the example above ?

Comment: For single page apps you would generally create all the components with a JS framework like Angular or React. The index.html would only contain a single div in the body.

Comment: SPA could be either or, IMO. That is dependent mostly on your requirements and possibly your framework. Most modern frameworks likely support dynamic page loading.

Comment: but it seems like every tutorial showing examples of SPA (lets say with angular.js) seems like the entire part of directives and attributes goes in the HTML. writing it all at the client seems to be a bit of a mess